# È "al riguardo" preferibile a "a riguardo" nel senso di "riguardo a ciò"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, prepositions

In [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1276/707) si è chiesto sulle espressioni "al riguardo di" e "a riguardo di" con il significato di "a paragone di", ma si è menzionato che "al riguardo" e "a riguardo" possono avere anche il senso di "about (something)", "regarding (something)". La mia domanda concerne soltanto questo ultimo significato. Cioè, chiedo unicamente sull'uso di queste locuzioni con il significato di "riguardo a ciò".

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9815/707) avevo scritto

> In spagnolo usiamo il termine "paraguayo" per designarla [...]: non so neanche da dove proviene questo nome (e non ho trovato nulla **a riguardo**), [...]

ma poi mi è stato suggerito di cambiare "a riguardo" con "al riguardo", con il commento seguente:

> L'uso prevalente è "al riguardo" non "a riguardo".

Ecco il mio dubbio: è veramente preferibile usare "al riguardo" invece di "a riguardo"?

Il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riguardo/) non lo lascia chiaro perché quando menziona queste locuzioni sembra attribuire loro unicamente il primo senso:

> meno com., *a r. di*, *al r. di*, in paragone di, rispetto a: *la luna è molto piccola a r. della terra*.

Ho trovato [questa discussione](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=2017) in cui pare si affermi che l'uso di "a riguardo" con questo significato non è corretto.

Non so fino a che punto la mia domanda sia in parte un duplicato della questione numero 2 che appare in [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1276/707). In ogni caso quella domanda la trovo più complessa.

Comment: @Gio: A proposito della tua modifica nel titolo, questa inversione verbo "essere"-soggetto nelle domande come si fa in inglese si usa anche in italiano?

Comment: @Gio:  Se n'era parlato in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5480/707) e mi sembra di capire che è una forma non idiomatica che suona piuttosto come un calco sintattico dall’inglese.

Comment: Ho modificato il titolo in base a come l’avrei espresso io, per come mi suona meglio. Comunque non penso si tratti di un’influenza anglofona, ma di regole della nostra grammatica. Vedi al punto 3.4 interrogative disgiunte. http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/interrogative-dirette_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/ - naturalmente puoi fare il reverse  del mio edit se preferisci.

Comment: @Gio: No, no, siete voi italiani gli esperti, io sto soltanto imparando la lingua. Ma allora vuol dire che [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5480/707) non è del tutto corretta quando afferma "La forma «È [qualcosa] corretto?» non è idiomatica, e suona piuttosto come un calco sintattico dall’inglese"? Qui si tratta di "È [qualcosa] preferibile [...]?" invece di "È [qualcosa] corretto?" però mi sembra la stessa struttura.

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: Essendo l'autore della risposta a cui mi riferisco nei miei commenti precedenti, mi piacerebbe avere la tua opinione. Sarebbe più naturale scrivere «"Al riguardo" è preferibile a [...]?» oppure «È preferibile "al riguardo" a [...]?»?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo Zanichelli suggerisce le seguenti forme: ***[al riguardo, a questo riguardo](http://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/parola-del-giorno/2012/05/11/riguardo__risguardo/)***:

> ***Relazione, attinenza***: ***al riguardo, a questo riguardo***, su questo problema, a questo proposito:
>
> - vorrei esprimere la mia opinione al riguardo; non posso darvi alcuna … notizia a questo riguardo (G. Leopardi).

come pure il Sabatini Coletti:

***[Riguardo](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/R/riguardo.shtml)***:

> ***Rapporto, attinenza***; usato oggi quasi soltanto in locc. || ***a questo riguardo, al riguardo***, a questo proposito.

Mi sembra che “a riguardo” non sia  altro che la forma abbreviata di “a questo riguardo”, per cui non direi che l’uso sia scorretto.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=al%20riguardo%2Ca%20riguardo%2Ca%20questo%20riguardo&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cal%20riguardo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20riguardo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20questo%20riguardo%3B%2Cc0) mostra un uso prevalente di “al riguardo”. Le espressioni  “a (questo) riguardo” sembrano essere meno usate.

Da notare anche il seguente uso di cui parla Treccani.it

***[“Riguardo a” o “riguardo”?](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/riguardo-a-o-riguardo_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)***

***La forma corretta è riguardo a, con preposizione***

> l’amministrazione USA è molto vaga riguardo ai suoi progetti per il dopoguerra («La Repubblica»)

***La forma senza la preposizione a, anche se molto diffusa, è scorretta***

> le statistiche che vengono diffuse fuori dall’Iraq riguardo le scuole e gli ospedali riaperti («Corriere della Sera»)
>
> ***Quest’uso è dovuto forse all’uso transitivo del verbo riguardare***, in costruzioni come per quanto riguarda qualcosa, per ciò che riguarda qualcosa.