# Si può usare "cambiare per" invece di "cambiare con" in qualche situazione?

Tags: word-usage, difference, prepositions

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9817/al-riguardo-%c3%a8-preferibile-a-a-riguardo-quando-hanno-il-senso-di-riguardo-a) avevo scritto

> poi mi è stato suggerito di cambiare "a riguardo" **per** "al riguardo"

ma questa frase è stata corretta in quest'altra

> poi mi è stato suggerito di cambiare "a riguardo" **con** "al riguardo"

in un aggiornamento ("edit"). Ho consultato la [voce "cambiare" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cambiare/) per cercare di capire la differenza tra "cambiare per" e "cambiare con" ma l'unico che sono riuscita a trovare è questa definizione

> Sostituire una persona, una cosa, **con** altra simile o diversa

che mi ha fatto pensare che, se si dice "sostituire con", molto probabilmente si dica anche "cambiare con". Non ho trovato, però, nessun esempio di uso di "cambiare per". Per questa ragione vi chiedo: ci sono situazioni in cui si può usare "cambiare per" invece di "cambiare con"? Potreste farne qualche esempio?

Comment: Infatti, su [Verbi italiani con preposizioni](http://www.italiano-online.it/verbi-Cconprep.html), "cambiare" appare con le preposizioni "in" e "con", ma non con "per".

Answer (score 2):

Nel suggerimento

```
[cambiare] "a riguardo" per "al riguardo"
```

la preposizione "per" assume il significato di "in favore di" o "in sostituzione a". A memoria, non mi sembra molto usato, ma è lecito come utilizzo.

Si può utilizzare la preposizione "per" in una frase del genere:

```
Non ho intenzione di cambiare per cambiare
```

In questo caso il senso è che chi parla non giustifica il cambiamento come fine a se stesso (utilizzo di "per" come preposizione indicante il fine).

Ho trovato a questo [link](https://libreriamo.it/scuola/il-corretto-uso-preposizione-per/) i possibili utilizzi della preposizione "per"

Comment: Nella spiegazione di Zanichelli che appare nel link che hai messo appare l'esempio "hai capito una cosa **per** un’altra". Si potrebbe  anche dire "hai cambiato una cosa **per** un’altra"?

Comment: @charo secondo me sì, è corretto, in questo caso "per" indica appunto una sostituzione.

Comment: Devo dire che mi suona un po' strana la costruzione “cambiare X per Y”, anche se si usa “per” con altri verbi di significato simile: “scambiare una persona per un'altra”, “prendere lucciole per lanterne”. Mi sentirei più sicuro se trovassimo esempi espliciti di “cambiare X per Y” in qualche grammatica, dizionario o testo di autore classico.

Comment: Mi associo anch'io a DaG: la costruzione, senz'altro comprensibile, mi suona molto bizzarra.

Comment: Le preposizioni, poi, sono legate al verbo. Usare sinonimi non significa poter usare automaticamente le stesse preposizioni (purtroppo…!).